# Why are the animations not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm asking for a little favor , I've started coding a website for my friend Micheal and just faced a little problem.
The slide menu animation is not working properly, as the the slide() (does the slide for the slide menu) works smoothly first time but the the returnBack() animation doesn't work smoothly (It does the job but not smoothly :( ) then the slide does the same thing in the second time : does the job , but not smoothly......
Here's the code (keep in mind that the animation is defined in the CSS file)

```js
var hero = document.querySelector(".hero"),
    sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");


document.querySelector(".menu-icon").addEventListener("click", function slide() {
    hero.style.animation = "slidehero 2s ease forwards";
    sidebar.style.animation = "slidebar 2s ease forwards";

});
document.querySelector("#Capa_1").addEventListener("click", function returnBack() {
    hero.style.animation = "slidehero 2s ease forwards reverse";
    sidebar.style.animation = "slidebar 2s ease forwards reverse";

});
```

```css
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local("Montserrat Black"), local("Montserrat-Black"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_epG3gnD_g.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Montserrat Bold"), local("Montserrat-Bold"), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v12/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_dJE3gnD_g.woff2) format("woff2");
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }
.container {
  background-color: #272223;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; }

.super-head {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 900; }

.side-back {
  background-color: #a6001c; }

@keyframes slidebar {
  0% {
    left: 0%; }
  50% {
    left: -25%; }
  100% {
    left: -50%; } }
@keyframes slidehero {
  0% {
    left: 0%; }
  50% {
    left: -50%; }
  100% {
    left: -100%; } }
body {
  width: 200%;
  overflow: hidden; }

.hero {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative; }

.hero .align-head {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; }

.hero .align-head .side-back {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative; }

.super-head {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block; }

.menu-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 6.21%;
  margin-top: 11.29%; }

[class^="rec-"] {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 53px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 3px; }

.menu-item {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  transition: text-decoration 3s; }

.menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through; }

.sidebar {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; }

.return {
  align-self: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  cursor: pointer; }

#Capa_1 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  cursor: pointer; }

.arrow:hover {
  fill: #a6001c; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section class="hero">
        <!--<h1 class="super-head">Greet<br>ings.</h1>--!>

        <div class="align-head">
            <div class="side-back">
                <div class="menu-icon">
                    <div class="rec-1"></div>
                    <div class="rec-2"></div>
                    <div class="rec-3"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <div class="sidebar">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 306 306" style="enable-background:new 0 0 306 306;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <g id="chevron-right">
  <polygon class="arrow" points="94.35,0 58.65,35.7 175.95,153 58.65,270.3 94.35,306 247.35,153   " fill="#ffffff"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>

        <a class="menu-item" src="#">About me</a>
        <a class="menu-item" src="#">Skills</a>
        <a class="menu-item" src="#">Works</a>
        <a class="menu-item" src="#">Contact me</a>


    </div>
</div>

<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="assets/js/textFit.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll give you an answer to your question, but just a future word of advise, try to post code that only pertains to what you are asking. Most of your css/html is irrelevant and it makes it harder for someone to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add animations also for your "returnBack" event. Something like this:

```CSS
@keyframes slidebarback {
  0% {
    left: -50%; }
  50% {
    left: -25%; }
  100% {
    left: 0%; } 
}

@keyframes slideheroback {
  0% {
    left: -100%; }
  50% {
    left: -50%; }
  100% {
    left: 0%; } 
}
```

```js
document.querySelector(".menu-icon").addEventListener("click", function slide() {
    hero.style.animation = "slidehero 2s ease forwards";
    sidebar.style.animation = "slidebar 2s ease forwards";

});

document.querySelector("#Capa_1").addEventListener("click", function returnBack() {
    hero.style.animation = "slideheroback 2s ease forwards";
    sidebar.style.animation = "slidebarback 2s ease forwards";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly skimming through your code I don't see any errors, but there could be a number of reasons for your problem.

It's hard to find out exactly what's wrong without knowing what browsers you have tested and your system specs. However if I had to take a guess I think 2 things could be at play.

First sometimes browsers need a little help dealing with css animations. Popular UI libraries like [materialize](https://materializecss.com/) utilize a css property called "[will-change](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/)". This property basically tells the browser that there will be a change coming soon to to that property and it gives the browser time to prepare.

Second some browsers still struggle to use new features properly. For more details on this you can checkout this answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552665/bluropacity-text-animation-makes-a-blink-in-google-chrome-browser/50553542#50553542).

If using the "will-change:transition" property doesn't fix your problem, the next thing I would try would be to remove the keyframes from your css code, and use the animate property instead.

That would basically look something like this:

Css:

```
.hero{transition: all 2s; transition-timing-function: ease;}
.sidebar{transition: all 2s; transition-timing-function: ease;}
```

Then your javascript would look like this:

```
document.querySelector(".menu-icon").addEventListener("click", function slide() {
    hero.style.left = "-50%";
    sidebar.style.left = "-100%";
});
```

I hope that helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Man your answer plus Fabio's answer helped me to figure it out but sadly his answer did 75% of the thing so I wish I could mark your answer but this wouldn't be fair, I really appreciate your effort and long answer and I pay my respects to people who are like you which make the internet a better place !